# In Unity3D, how can I stop the editor from executing an editor extention script that is stuck in an error loop?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

In Unity3D, I have created the below editor extension and it worked but got stuck in an endless error loop.  How can I stop the editor from executing it?  I have tried Ctrl-c and Ctrl-z but no luck.  I would prefer not to restart the editor but I can do that if it is the only way.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;


public class ConfigureLevelPart : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/AddCollidersToChildren", false, 0)]
    static void testFunction1()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in Selection.activeGameObject.transform)
        {
            if (child.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>())
            {
                child.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
                child.gameObject.isStatic = true;
                child.gameObject.tag = "World";
                child.gameObject.layer = 12; //layer 12 is world
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are:

```
[PathTracer] AddGeometry job with hash: 151d6786c86f1a0497062c3ce74bf71b failed with exit code 1.
```

and

```
[PathTracer] Failed to add geometry; mesh is missing required attribute. Please make sure mesh contains positions, normals and texcoord0.
```

and these just keep repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I found out the specific issue in this case.  However I still do not have a general solution.

In my case, my editor script triggered lighting to re-bake because I had auto-generate turned on.  There must be an error in my scene and this caused an endless error loop for some reason.  My temporary solution was to go into the lighting settings and turn off auto-generate and cancel the bake.

Comment: The problem might be related to you setting `child.gameObject.isStatic = true;` which makes your object/mesh applicable for static illumination, so yes if you have auto-generate on it all the time tries to re-bake these static objects for static lights

Comment: Thank you derHugo, ```child.gameObject.isStatic = true;``` was indeed the issue just like you stated.